# Make Xtrabackup ignore myisam tables & backup only innoDB tables?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, backup, xtrabackup

I'm using mysql 5.7 (or rather percona 5.7)

Is it possible to backup only the innodb tables (easily, not to specify each table one by one because I have a lot of tables) with xtrabackup? and not take into account myisam tables that are read-only?

If I remember right, if you have myisam tables it will lock the whole DB thus breaking the application during the backup procedure.

Comment: , welcome to the site. what is the edition of mysql server?

Comment: mysql 5.7, forgot to add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Xtrabackup website](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup/supported-technologies) says something different:

> Percona XtraBackup can back up the following storage engines by briefly pausing writes at the end of the backup

This information used to be in the documentation, probably better detailed, but nowadays only this enigmatic claim remains. Probably you are worrying too much, but I will answer the rest of the question anyway.

There doesn't seem to be any way to easily exclude non-InnoDB tables from the backup. What you can do is to manually exclude those tables with [--table-exclude](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.3/xtrabackup_bin/xbk_option_reference.html#cmdoption-xtrabackup-tables-exclude) If you have entire databases dedicated to non-InnoDB tables, [--databases-exclude](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.3/xtrabackup_bin/xbk_option_reference.html#cmdoption-xtrabackup-databases-exclude) should be easier to use.

You can dynamically compose the list of those tables with this query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME) SEPARATOR ',')
    FROM information_schema.TABLES
    WHERE
        ENGINE <> 'InnoDB'
        AND ENGINE IS NOT NULL
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN (
            'mysql',
            'performance_schema',
            'information_schema',
            'sys'
        );
```

Comment: Look like `ENGINE = 'InnoDB'` is required, isn't it?

Comment: Good answer, I'll try this (unless there is an even better solution). Thank you. By the way, I had tried and it effectively locked my whole application because the read only myisam tables are HUGE

Comment: @Kondybas: no, the query must return a list of non-InnoDB tables - the ones we want to exclude from the backup.

Comment: @pedrotester I understand. Did you consider to convert them to InnoDB? This would also avoid data losses if MySQL crashes.

Comment: Yes but since they are huge (at least it seems to me,  probably more than 200mb of read only tables), it seems like it would be better to stick to MyISAM instead of cnverting them all to innodb. Especially after reading this https://jfg-mysql.blogspot.com/2017/08/why-we-still-need-myisam.html

Comment: That article mentions compressed tables. Is that your case? Also, 200M are not many. I would simply use InnoDB tables. You can even compress them, but probably it would be better to get bigger disks.

Comment: @FedericoRazzoli sorry forgot to read this, in fact it's 500MB of read only. But if you say let's use InnoDB instead, then why not. But in the article he also says it's faster (and I noticed this, the app takes like 30% more time to initialize aka reading all the tables, which is roughly 10s on a slow server :D)

Comment: @pedrotester if MySQL was not shutdown properly or innodb_fast_shutdown=1, at startup InnoDB has to scan the transaction logs to apply all committed changes. InnoDB has no reason to "read all the tables", it just applies changes to keep the .ibd updated. This shouldn't affect you, because you say that your tables are read-only. Writing into InnoDB tables is slower, yes, but you also have guarantees not to lose data in case of a crash. Are your reads slower on InnoDB? This can happen with queries on secondary indexes, but the problem should always be solvable.

Comment: yes, reads are slower, but I wouldn't know how to improve speed, far from being a pro